# How to add the camera on a web application in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, camera

I come to you because I have a problem that I can’t solve.

I’m currently building a web application in react.js, and I’m trying to implement the camera function. In localhost on my computer, everything works, but I can’t launch the camera mode on my phone.

I have this mistake:

**"Camera error: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."**

I know that with the “react-html5-camera-photo” library, the camera with “getusermedia” is not supported on iPhone with chrome or firebox, so I work under Safari, but I can’t find solutions despite many attempts.
I also looked at how to give the rights to Safari on my iPhone, but I can’t find a solution.

So if you know how to get the camera function on your mobile in react.js, I’m a taker!

Thank you in advance for your answers !

My code :

```
onTakePhoto (dataUri) {
  // Do stuff with the dataUri photo...
  //console.log('takePhoto');
  console.log(dataUri);
  this.setState(() => ({dataUri}));
  storage.ref('images').putString(dataUri, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpg'}).then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log('takePhoto')
  });

}

render() {

    return (
            <div style={style}>
            <Link to='/'>
                <button>Back</button>
            </Link>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <progress value={this.state.progress} max="100"/>
            <br/>
            <Camera
              onTakePhoto = { (dataUri) => { this.onTakePhoto(dataUri); } }
            />
                <button onClick={this.screenshot.bind(this)}>Capture</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                { this.state.url ? <img src={this.state.url} /> : null }
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this =>

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

Source => https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebRTC/Prendre_des_photos_avec_la_webcam ?